# Problems with global variables, pickle, that sort of thing

Tags: python, global, pickle, eof

This is my first post. I am getting the error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
> File "intruder.py", line 47, in <module>
>     main()
> File "intruder.py", line 16, in main
>     readfile()
> File "intruder.py", line 34, in readfile
>     pickle.load(f)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1378, in load
>     return Unpickler(file).load()
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
>     dispatch[key](self)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
>     raise EOFError
> EOFError
> ```

**For code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import getpass
import bz2
import pickle
import marshal
import os, sys
global data
global firsttime
global password
global user
fp = open("firsttime.txt", "r")
data = fp.read();
firsttime = data
def main():
    readfile()
    name = raw_input('What is your name? ')
    if name == user:
        user_input = getpass.getpass('Enter Password: ')
        if user_input != password:
            print "Intruder alert!"
            main()
    if name != user:
        print "Intruder alert!"
        main()
    print "Login Successful! "
def savefile():
    n = open("settings.pkl", 'wb')
    pickle.dump(user, n, 2)
    pickle.dump(password, n, 2)
    n.close()
def readfile():
    f = open("settings.pkl", "rb")
    pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
if data < 1:
    user = raw_input ("Enter desired username: ")
    password = getpass.getpass('Enter desired password: ')
    # encrypted_password = bz2.compress(password)
    # bz2.decompress(encrypted_password)
    data = 2
    g = open("firsttime.txt", "rb")
    outf.write(g(data))
    g.close()
    savefile()
if data > 1:
    main()
```

EDIT: I fixed the above problem. I changed:

```
fp = open("firsttime.txt", "r")
```

to:

```
fp = file("firsttime.txt", "r")
```

And now it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "intruder.py", line 47, in <module>
        main()
    File "intruder.py", line 17, in main
    if name == user:
NameError: global name 'user' is not defined
```

This is strange, because user is defined as the user's raw_input, and it askes me for it right before this error appears.

Comment: Does the file "settings.pkl" exist? Is there anything in it? You may need the full path to it, rather than a relative path?

Comment: I think the error suggests that the file exists, but is empty. Can't be sure though.

Answer (score 1):

The `global` keyword tells Python that you're refering to a global variable.
It doesn't create the variable.

You need to change to the following.

Global defs, remove the `global data` definitions you have and replace with this:

```
data = None
firsttime = None
password = None
user = None
```

Then in your functions you tell Python that you're refering to the global, not a local variable. This is only required to write to the variable, not read from it.

```
def main():
    global user, firsttime, password, user
<snip>
def savefile():
    global user, firsttime, password, user
<snip>
def readfile():
    global user, firsttime, password, user
<snip>
```

Apart from that, the code has other issues (fp is never closed, etc), but I won't critique other issues.